# Properly process nested array structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am trying to process the below array using javascript. I need to loop through each group and its children and do something with the final result. I need to maintain a relationship from the parent to all of its groups/children. I thought I could achieve this using recursion, but I am failing to do so.

```
const columnGroups = [
  {
    label: "Grand Parent1",
    groupId: "gp1",
    children: [
      {
        label: "Group 1",
        groupId: "group1",
        children: [{ field: "group1_field1" }, { field: "group1_field2" }]
      },
      {
        label: "Group 2",
        groupId: "group2",
        children: [{ field: "group2_field1" }, { field: "group2_field2" }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Grand Parent2",
    groupId: "gp2",
    children: [
      {
        label: "Group 3",
        groupId: "group3",
        children: [
          {
            label: "Group 4",
            groupId: "group4",
            children: [{ field: "group4_field1" }]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I have created a stackblitz to show what I have done so far:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-g37a33?file=index.ts

**More clarification**

As I loop through the groups, I need to create columns and add the children to the column to form a group.

For example the first item in the array with the groupId `gp1`: When I get to that item, I need to create a column with that id. Then I can see that it has children, which are also groups, so I create another column with the id `group1` and add that as a child to `gp1`. I do the same with `group2`. Essentially I need to re-create the structure of `columnGroups`.

Comment: Please put the relevant code as a [mcve] in the question itself. What is your input and expected output? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have something like this:

You data structure is like:

An array of object, which may have a `children` property, which is in turn of an array of object (recursion). But each item in the children array might just have a `field` that is of interest, which can be processed or printed out in this case.

```js
function processItems(arr, level = 0) {
  for (const e of arr) {
    if (e.label || e.groupId) console.log(`${" ".repeat(level * 4)}For ${e.label} ${e.groupId}`);
    if (e.field) console.log(`${" ".repeat(level * 4)}${e.field}`);
    if (e.children)
      processItems(e.children, level + 1);
  }
}

const columnGroups = [{
    label: "Grand Parent1",
    groupId: "gp1",
    children: [{
        label: "Group 1",
        groupId: "group1",
        children: [{
          field: "group1_field1"
        }, {
          field: "group1_field2"
        }]
      },
      {
        label: "Group 2",
        groupId: "group2",
        children: [{
          field: "group2_field1"
        }, {
          field: "group2_field2"
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Grand Parent2",
    groupId: "gp2",
    children: [{
      label: "Group 3",
      groupId: "group3",
      children: [{
        label: "Group 4",
        groupId: "group4",
        children: [{
          field: "group4_field1"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
];

processItems(columnGroups)
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks good. Can I somehow maintain the parent groups along with the output?

Comment: I have made it print out the parent group and label

Comment: Thanks again @nopole. That helps. I added some more information into my question on what exactly I am trying to achieve. I will try that with your code and see how far I get.

Comment: Is it possible to print the following for example in line `For Group 1 group1`, I want to show `Parent1` as well and in `group1_field1`, I want to show `group1`? Basically showing the parent groupId from the current item.

Comment: When you say "For example the first item in the array with the groupId gp1: When I get to that item, I need to create a column with that id. Then I can see that it has children, which are also groups, so I create another column with the id group1 and add that as a child to gp1. I do the same with group2. Essentially I need to re-create the structure of columnGroups." What is "create a column"? Create it as data structure, or print it out? Or what do you want?

Comment: Can you list and write out exactly what the expected result should look like, and whether you want it printed out or create the same data structure all over again? You know you cannot be vague and hope people help you indefinitely.